# POST Request to add a AttachmentWrapper in Archer

Tags: python-3.x, rest, post, postman, rsa-archer-grc

I am trying to call a post request to upload a file to Archer. Please find my code below :

```
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    data = open('testdoc.txt','rb').read()

    url = "http://rsaarcher/platformapi/core/content/attachment" #my archer url

    token = "<my session id token>"
    headers = {
       'Accept':'application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Authorization': 'Archer session-id="'+token+'"',
       'content-type': "application/json;",
       'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }
   response = requests.request("POST", url, data=data, headers=headers, verify = False)

   print(response.content)
   print(response.status_code)
```

I am getting the following error :
       b'{"Message":"The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type \'application/octet-stream\' is not supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type \'AttachmentWrapper\' from content with media type \'application/octet-stream\'.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}'
Status code : 415

Answer (score 0):

Nakshatra, did you convert the file you're uploading to base64 beforehand?

Comment: Yes @DjP, I have used below code for this , but its giving me the same error only  :                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   [ with open("1.png", "rb") as img_file:
       data = base64.b64encode(img_file.read()) ]

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I realized the data you're sending is the incorrect formatted.  It should be as follows:

```js
{
    "AttachmentName" : "myFile.docx",
    "AttachmentBytes" : "[base64 here]"
}
```

Comment: Yeah @DjP , I am sending the base64 data in the same format. I will attach the entire code I am using.